# Filter simpleadapter listview

Tags: android

hi i have a problem on filtering simpleadapterlistview , when i type in the edit text the app keeps on crashing please help me .

// here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

//    TextView lbl;
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    Button btnimport;
    Button btnexport;
    Button btnsearch;
    EditText search;
    ListView lv;
    final Context context = this;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
    public static final int requestcode = 1;
    public final static String ID_EXTRA1 = "com.example.ansiuser.uploadfile.MainActivity.Id";
    public final static String ID_EXTRA = "com.example.ansiuser.uploadfile.MainActivity.Category";
    public final static String ID_EXTRA2 = "com.example.ansiuser.uploadfile.MainActivity.Code";
    public final static String ID_EXTRA3 = "com.example.ansiuser.uploadfile.MainActivity.Description";
    public final static String ID_EXTRA4 = "com.example.ansiuser.uploadfile.MainActivity.Unit";
    public final static String ID_EXTRA5 = "com.example.ansiuser.uploadfile.MainActivity.Quantity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
        btnimport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
        btnexport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexport);
        lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView cat;
                TextView code;
                TextView desc;
                TextView unit;
                TextView quan;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);



                cat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtproductcompany);
                String gory = cat.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, gory);

                code = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtproductname);
                String deco = code.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA2, deco);

                desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtproductprice);
                String csed = desc.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA3, csed);

                unit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtunit);
                String noti = unit.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA4, noti);

                quan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtquan);
                String quanti = quan.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA5, quanti);

                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA1 , String.valueOf(id + 1));
                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });

        btnexport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            SQLiteDatabase database = controller.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = null;
            @Override
            public void  onClick (View v){
                 try
                 {
                     c = database.rawQuery("Select * FROM Countsheet" , null);
                     int rowcount = 0;
                     int colcount = 0;
                     File sdCardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                     String filename = "/Count2.csv";
                     File saveFile = new File(sdCardDir,filename);
                     FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(saveFile);

                     BufferedWriter bw  = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                     rowcount = c.getCount();
                     colcount = c.getColumnCount();

                     if (rowcount > 0 )
                         c.moveToFirst();
                        for (int i = 0 ; i < colcount; i++)
                        {
                            if (i != colcount -1){
                                bw.write(c.getColumnName(i) + ",");
                            }
                            else {
                                bw.write(c.getColumnName(i));
                            }
                        }
                     bw.newLine();
                     for (int i = 0; i < rowcount;i++){
                         c.moveToPosition(i);
                         for (int j = 0;j < colcount;j++){
                             if (j != colcount-1)
                             {
                                 bw.write(c.getString(j)+ ",");
                             }else
                             {
                                 bw.write(c.getString(j));
                             }

                         }
                         bw.newLine();
                         bw.flush();

//                         lbl.setText("Exported Successfully.");

                     }


                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                    if (database.isOpen()){
                        database.close();
//                        lbl.setText(ex.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                 }finally {

                 }

            }
        });

        btnimport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                fileintent.setType("gagt/sdf");
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(fileintent, requestcode);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
//                    lbl.setText("No activity can handle picking a file. Showing alternatives.");
                }

            }
        });
        myList= controller.getAllProducts();
        if (myList.size() != 0) {
            ListView lv = getListView();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList,
                    R.layout.v, new String[]{"Category", "Code", "Description" , "Unit" , "Quantity"}, new int[]{
                    R.id.txtproductcompany, R.id.txtproductname, R.id.txtproductprice , R.id.txtunit , R.id.txtquan});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
//            lbl.setText("");
        }
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ((SimpleAdapter)MainActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
```

//here is the log error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.ansiuser.uploadfile, PID: 14657
                  **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getFilter()'** on a null object reference
                      at com.example.ansiuser.uploadfile.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter is not initialized. Make the adapter global  and initialize in onCreate.

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this, yourList, ...)
```

Comment: You are creating a local variable again 

`ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(..) `

instead use the global variable you declared earlier! change to 

 `adapter = new SimpleAdapter(..)`

Comment: SIR THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR KINDNESS IT WORKS :)